# Flash TextField -- make it act like a label?

Tags: flash, label, textfield, behavior

How can i disable the text selection abilities and such of flash TextFields (so they act like labels)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In code, you can do it like this:

```
myTextField.selectable = false;
```

Or you can untick the "Selectable" button (an A and a selected b) in the Properties panel for the TextField in the Flash CS IDE.